# bootstrap 4 scroll only mid column /facebook like scroll

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

i have 3 column in bootstrap and i want the scroll only the middle dive while keeping the position relative to the parent container . something like facebook scroll

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">stop scrolling when content end </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> SCROLL </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> stop scrolling when content end </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i tried using position fixed , but when i use it .it messes the grid system , thats why i want the position to stay relative to the parent if possible .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can use `sticky-top` like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/IL1wlzpNEP

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> <div class="sticky-top">side</div> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> SCROLL </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> <div class="sticky-top">side</div> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The middle column will scroll the length of its' content.